# Finding a closed subset of all bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

I stumbled upon this question when reading up about analysis, and it's stumped me. Hoping for some hints:

Let $X$ be any nonempty set, and $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Let $\mathcal{F}(X , \mathbb K)$ be the set of all functions from $X$ to $\mathbb K$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_0(X , \mathbb K)=\lbrace f\in \mathcal{F}(X , \mathbb K) : \forall \epsilon>0, \lbrace x \in X : |f(x)|\geq \epsilon \rbrace$ is finite $\rbrace$

Finally, let $l^\infty(X , \mathbb K)$ be the set of all bounded functions in $\mathcal{F}(X , \mathbb K)$.

The claim I want to prove is that $\mathcal{F}_0(X , \mathbb K)\subseteq l^\infty(X , \mathbb K)$, and in fact that $\mathcal{F}_0(X , \mathbb K)$ is a closed subset of $l^\infty(X , \mathbb K)$.

The crux of the first part seems to be finding a number that bounds $f$, given that $f$ is in $\mathcal{F}_0$. I feel like this should be fairly easy, and make use of the fact that we have a finite set to work with, but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just let $\mathbb K=\mathbb C$ for simplicity (since $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$). If $f\in\mathcal F_0(X,\mathbb C)$, then $|f(x)|\geqslant1$ for only finitely many $x$, e.g. $x_1, \ldots, x_m$. Put $M=1 + \max_{1\leqslant i\leqslant m}|f(x_i)|$, then clearly $|f(x)|\leqslant M$ for all $x\in X$, so $f\in l^\infty(X,\mathbb C)$.

To show that $\mathcal F_0(X,\mathbb C)$ is closed, let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathcal F_0(X,\mathbb C)$ with a limit $f\in l^\infty(X,\mathbb C)$. Then you need to show that $f\in\mathcal F_0(X,\mathbb C)$, i.e. given $\varepsilon>0$, $|f(x)|\geqslant\varepsilon$ for only finitely many $x\in X$.

Comment: Thanks, very useful post. I think for the closed part, I just need to search my brain for some definitions of convergence that I know.

One more thing, do you mean $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, or just pointwise?

Comment: Just pointwise. Recall that a set in a metric space is closed if and only if it contains all of its limit points.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, $\{x \in X: |f(x)| \geq 1\}$ is a finite set, call it $Y$, so $f$ is bounded by $\max\{|f(y)|: y \in Y\}$, or by $1$ if $Y = \emptyset$.

Proof: Call the proposed bound $b$. Note that $1 \leq b$. If $y \in Y$ then $|f(y)| \leq b$ by definition of $b$. If $y \notin Y$ then $|f(y)| < 1 \leq b$. Either way $|f(y)| \leq b$.

Comment: Should it be $max \lbrace |f(y)|:y\in Y \rbrace$? $f(y)$ could be a complex number, so it may not have an ordering before taking the modulus.

Anyway, thanks for the comment, although it's still not clear to me that what you've described is a bound for the function.

Comment: @Ducky Yes, you're right about the modulus signs. Does my edit help you understand why it's a bound?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to me now. Thanks for the help!